# Problem with Firebase realtime database rules after migrating to Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've got a web app from 2014 that's still using `firebase-token-generator` to generate custom auth tokens on the backend, and Firebase JS SDK 2.x on the client side.

This is an open source project, but nobody can host it by themselves anymore, because when one creates a new Firebase project, the token necessary for the deprecated `firebase-token-generator` library to work is no longer generated.

I decided to migrate it to Firebase Admin SDK and most recent version of JS SDK. I thought it went smoothly and I don't get any errors, but it looks like some of the rules that worked fine before, no longer work as expected. Here are the database rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "rooms": {
      "$roomid": {
        // You can see people in the room only if you are in it as well
        ".read": "auth != null && data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
        "users": {
          "$uid": {
            // You can modify only your own info
            ".write": "auth != null && $uid == auth.uid",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a simplified client code:

```js
      const firebaseConfig = {...};
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      // Get custom auth token from the server
      const response =  await fetch('/auth');
      const data = await response.json();

      const auth = window.firebase.auth();
      await auth.signInWithCustomToken(data.token);

      const user = { uuid: data.id };
      const roomName = 'firebase-test'

      const database = window.firebase.database();
      const connectionRef = database.ref('.info/connected');
      const roomRef = database.ref(`rooms/${roomName}`);
      const usersRef = roomRef.child('users');
      const userRef = usersRef.child(data.id);

      window.users = {};

      connectionRef.on('value', (connectionSnapshot) => {
        if (connectionSnapshot.val() === true) {
          // Remove yourself from the room when disconnected
          userRef.onDisconnect().remove();

          // Add yourself to the room
          userRef.set(user);

          // Watch for added users
          usersRef.on('child_added', (userAddedSnapshot) => {
            const addedUser = userAddedSnapshot.val();
            window.users[addedUser.uuid] = addedUser;
          });

          // Watch for removed users
          usersRef.on('child_removed', (userRemovedSnapshot) => {
            const removedUser = userRemovedSnapshot.val();
            delete window.users[removedUser.uuid];
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

and server code:

```js
app.get('/auth', async (req, res, next) => {
  const uid = uuidv4();
  const token = await firebaseAdmin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
  res.json({ id: uid, token });
});
```

Now, I don't get any errors, but e.g. when a user closes or reloads the page, sometimes they are no longer removed from the database. Sometimes users don't get updates about new users who were added. I tried debugging it with the Firebase emulator, but all I could figure out is that checks like `$uid == auth.uid` in the database rules started to fail sometimes, even though they worked fine before the migration.

I created 2 demos to show this isssue. Here's a link to the version that uses old SDK: https://codesandbox.io/s/firebase-issue-test-old-sdk-loukt, and here's one that uses the new SDK: https://codesandbox.io/s/firebase-issue-test-new-sdk-c9lwh. If you open the latter in 2 tabs, then reload one tab, then reload the other tab, then reload the first tab again, and so on, you'll see that users are not removed. The version that uses old SDK works as expected. Both versions have almost exactly the same client-side code.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong with this code and how to make sure that users who close the page are correctly removed from the database?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the user may not be signed in anymore when the `onDisconnect` handler is called. You might want to capture that separately in your code, essentially allowing unauthenticated deletes:

```
".write": "(auth != null && $uid == auth.uid) ||
           (auth == null && !newData.exists())",
```

---

Note that your code is only using a single property to track the user's connection, which is going lead to false negatives (the user being marked as not being online, when actually they are) in the case where the user's device disconnect-and-reconnects. A common scenario for this:

1. Device is connected, and has written its `userRef`.
2. Device loses connection, e.g. the user goes into a tunnel. This is a so-called dirty disconnect, and in this scenario it takes a few minutes before the server detects that the client is gone.
3. Device creates a new connection, e.g. the user comes out of the tunnel. This new connection writes to `userRef` again.
4. The server detects that the original connection is gone, and deletes the data at `userRef`.

Now you have no presence information for the user at `userRef` anymore, despite the device having a connection.

The above is the most common scenario, but there actually are more similar situations. For this reason it is best to allow tracking multiple connections per user, as shown in the [presence system in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample).

The logic here is that a user is only if their node exists, no matter how many connection nodes exists under that.

Comment: Thanks! I added the rule you suggested, but it doesn't help. There's something really strange going on here.

Let's say that the database is empty and I open this page in tab A. I can see that the user is added and if I keep reloading the page, the user is removed and added properly.

When I open this page in another tab B, I can correctly see 2 users. I can keep reloading this tab B and always see 2 users. 

However, when I at this point reload tab A, I get 3 users as the first user is not removed. If I now reload tab B, I get 4 users and so on...

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not sure what's going on there. Can you set up a repro on a site like jsbin or stackblitz?

Comment: Thanks! I created 2 projects on CodeSandbox - one with the new SDK and one with the old SDK, both connected to the same Firebase realtime db with the same security rules. As both projects include a server and a Firebase service account private key, could I send you link to both e.g. on Twitter?

Comment: Hey Frank!

Here's a link to the version that uses old SDK: https://codesandbox.io/s/firebase-issue-test-old-sdk-loukt, here's one that uses new SDK: https://codesandbox.io/s/firebase-issue-test-new-sdk-c9lwh

If you open the latter in 2 tabs, then reload one tab, then reload the other tab, then reload the first tab again, etc. you'll see that users are not removed. The version that uses old SDK works as expected. Both versions have almost exactly the same client-side code.